# Modify Child Element (color) in ExpandableListView from outside of Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

There are two Fragments:
-Fragment A - has a button
-Fragment B - has an exapndablelistview
both visible at the same time.

After pressing the button the color of one of child elements of the expandablelistview should change. I will know which parent and child id it is going to be. But how to access the child element from the Fragment B class rather than BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a member variable in the class of the child element to keep track of the color of it. Then you need your ListAdapter to change the color of the child element based on this new member variable. Now when the button is pressed simply change this color variable and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the ListAdapter.

Example:

```
class ChildElement {
    int color;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildElement e = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    ...
    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(e.color);
    ...
}
```

Then to change the color

```
elements.get(position).color = newColor;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: The only question I would have how to change back the color for previous item. I thought that 'notifyDataSetChanged();' will do the trick but unfortunately I have now two items modified.

Comment: One way you could do this is simply to loop through all your elements and reset all their colors. Then set the color of the element you want. Another method is to remember the last element you set the color for and reset the last element everytime you set the color for a new element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how I did that: I have two variables i.e. default color and new color. Inside getChildView here is the piece of code I use

```
    if (child.getId() == currentlyActiveChild) {
        txtListChild.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        txtListChild.setTextColor(defaultChildColor);
    }
```

Obviously inside Adapter I have

```
public void setActiveChild(long newID) {
    currentlyActiveChild = newID;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```